# Changing drop-down selection with jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, dom-traversal

I am trying to figure out how to change the selection of multiple select boxes.

Here is what I currently have:

```
function selectStrategies() {  
    $('#dataTable tr').each(function() {
        if($(this).find("td").eq(0).html()) { 
            $(this).find("td select").val($('#mainStrategyChoice').val()); 
        }   
    });
}
```

I have a main drop-down box. When the selection of that box is changed, I call the selectStrategies function which suppose to adjust the selection for all rows in the table. The provide code above worked perfectly until I had to add second drop-down box for each row. I am trying to find a way to refer to first and second drop-down box.

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm someone posted an answer and removed it I wanted to accept that answer. All I had to do is $(this).find("td select").eq(0).val($('#mainStrategyChoice').val());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there anything specific on those first and second select boxes? A class, an ID, or even a name could help, because you can target those (or part of those) with jQuery selectors. If there is nothing like that, for convenience you should add something common to the `select`s you want to target.

For `class="firstSelect"`:

```
$(this).find("td select.firstSelect").val($('#mainStrategyChoice').val());
```

If the `name` is always sg like `first-213`, `first-84`, etc.:

```
$(this).find("td select[name^="first-"]").val($('#mainStrategyChoice').val());
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I tried it and it works as well as the previous answer I got (in my comment). Since whoever posted previous answer removed it I guess I will accept yours. :)